# Ruby start_with? inconsistency

Tags: ruby

Please tell me how the first use of start_with returned false.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: i just ran it 5 times. still the same

Comment: Can you please paste your code into your question instead of the screenshot. Perhaps one of the chars just looks like a `#`, but is actually another uft8 character.

Comment: i'm using ruby 2.1.2p95

Comment: the code itself uses a string variable, so i thought it wouldn't be helpful in that way. also, i am very sure it's a number sign.

Comment: i copy pasted that from the output of the parser i was writing

Comment: i got `0000000 23 68 6f 77 20 74 6f 20 64 6f 77 6e 6c 6f 61 64`

Comment: Please set `str =` your string, run `str.start_with?("#")` and `str[0,10].encode('utf-8').chars.each { |c| puts c.ord }` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Further to @Jesse's comment, I mean for you to insert `str = ` in front of the troublesome string in your code. What I gave you will tell us what the first 10 Unicode characters in the string are.

Comment: @CarySwoveland i got this `["", "#", "h", "o", "w", " ", "t", "o", " ", "d"]`

Comment: Please check the code you used to get that result. What I gave you includes `puts c.ord`, which prints an integer.

Comment: oh yes. i got these: `65279
35
104
111
119
32
116
111
32
100` i solved my problem. thanks for your help!

Comment: I've just tried to paste the code as text, but unfortunately the BOM is stripped by SO once you submit the change.

Comment: Unicode 65279 is a 'zero width no-break space' (`U+FEFF`), as @JesseSielaff reports in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string may contain a hidden unicode character.

If so, the string starts with that character, not with `#`, which is why you're getting `false`.

To see it in Ruby, take the string you're running `start_with?` on and instead run `.unpack('C*')`. This will return an array of numbers between `0` and `255`, representing the integer values of every byte in the string. Normal printable ASCII characters only go up to `126`. Any number higher than that will be a clue that there is a non-printing character hiding in your string.

**UPDATE**

In this particular case, it turned out that using this diagnostic method showed that there were indeed extra bytes at the beginning of the string. They appeared at the beginning of the array as `[239, 187, 191, ...]`, the string equivalent of which is `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"` or the UTF-8 codepoint *ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE*, which is inserted as a *byte-order mark* at the beginning of a file by some text editors.

Comment: i got this. how do i interpret this? `[-17, -69, -65, 35, 104, 111, 119, 32, 116, 111, 32, 100, 111, 119, 110, 108, 111, 97, 100, 32, 109, 101, 109, 116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 112, 108, 117, 115, 32, 55, 13, 10]`

Comment: You can open files in `r:bom|utf-8` mode to strip the BOM.